# generate image from qrcode node js and upload itto firebase

Tags: node.js

i got image from qrcode use node js but i need to get this image and store it in firebase help me please, i tryed to get URL of qrcode and convert it to buffer an then i store it in firebase but i check my storage in firebase the image has 0 bytes size can any one help me please????

```
exports.createImage = (value) => {
  const image = QRCode.toFile("qr.png", value, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  console.log("qr.png created", image);
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.